# rotated vertical tabs for chrome or firefox

Tags: browser, tabs

Is there any way to get vertical tabs in firefox or chrome? And not just tabs on the side (which looks stupid) but to actually have them rotated -90 degrees on the left ( or 90 degrees on the right)? If there isn't something like this yet, is it possible to create as an extension or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Rotated 90 degrees on either side means you would have to read up-down (sideways) instead of left-right. With today's wide-screen monitors, having tabs along the side makes total sense. Screen real estate is available there, you can see 15-30 tabs at a time (depending on your screen size and resolution), and you can scroll through the rest.

No, I've never seen what you're asking for. And just imagining it right now is giving me a headache. :)

Comment: I just think that having vertical tabs taking up 300px of space on my screen is a waste.

Comment: I'm guessing that 300px is an exaggeration!

Comment: So make them smaller. There should be a gripper that lets you resize it, just like frames in some web pages.